# My Downloadable Products links issue

Tags: customer-account, magento-2.1.7

If you log in to an account, then view "My Account", when click a link named **My Downloadable Products** in the left nav area, it gives **404 Not Found**.  URL for this is siteurl **/downloadable/customer/products/**

I got this error message while this happens:

> 2018/01/31 15:07:55 [error] 22514#0: *113332 "/home/abc/magento/downloadable/customer/products/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 121.59.59.001, server: siteurl.com, request: "GET /downloadable/customer/products/ HTTP/1.1", host: "siteurl.com", referrer: "siteurl.com/customer/address/"

Why this should happen while this works good on other site?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue after lot of debugging. This issue is  cause of an redirection rule.

In conf file, an rewrite rule is set as

> location /download {
>           rewrite ^(/download$) $scheme://$server_name/? permanent;
>       }

This rule checks for the whole pattern an give that error. I changed the rule to

> location = /download {
>           rewrite ^(/download$) $scheme://$server_name/? permanent;
>       }

And now the link for the  **My Downloadable Products** is working fine.